# How to add the "upload PDF" option in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am collecting certificates from the students of my section. I have entered some entities as Name, Event Date, Venue etc.

I want to add an upload pdf file option in the Google Sheet. Is it possible to do so?

I am not so good at Google Sheets etc.

Comment: For collecting data rather than using google sheet, directly … You may use Google form. and link it with google sheet. Google form have option to upload file which will be store in your google drive.

Comment: @DevenRamani Yeah that option is known to me. But I want to have in the Sheet itself

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "attach" files to a Google Sheet. A possible workaround: Create a folder in Google Drive. Adjust the permissions so that all those who need to upload PDFs have access to upload to it. Place a link to this folder in the spreadsheet with upload instructions.

You can also get links to the uploaded PDF files and place them in the cells of your spreadsheet. See here: https://riptutorial.com/google-apps-script/example/15117/get-all-files-in-a-drive-folder